# Database Codeigniter query

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a problem with extracting data from the database only for a given record in Code Igniter.

In my application I have domains to which I can add my comments - everything is overwhelmed.

I can add, edit, delete domains and notes.

However, when I step in on whatever domain card appears, all notes and I would like to display only those for the selected domain.

I think the problem is on the side of the SQL query - which must compare two tables: the **id** from the **domains** table and the **id_rel_domain** from the notes table.

However, I have no idea how to embrace it.

I have a linked relationship in the **SQL FOREIGN KEY on ALTER TABLE** database:  notes.id_domain_rel with domains.id.

My code (CodeIgniter)

My controller:

```
public function get($id = false)
{
    $result = $this->notes_model->get($id);
    echo '{"records":' . json_encode( $result ) . '}';
}
```

My models:

```
public function get( $id = false)
    {
        if ( $id == false ) {
            $q = $this->db->get('notes');
            $q = $q->result();
        }
        else{
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $q = $this->db->get('notes');
            $q = $q->row();
        }
        return $q;
    }
```

The second condition is needed to edit notes - because it gets their ID.
The first one, however, is displayed all notes for all domains.

In my opinion, I must add:

```
$this->db->where('notes.id_domain_rel', $domain.id);
```

However, I miss the idea of ​​how to do it.

Gets data for all domains, not for one I have a view of.
[image]

Comment: Gets data for all domains, not for one I have a view of.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a problem with the condition checking.  try using **===** in the if statement. or use **NULL** instead of boolean values.

```
 public function get( $id = false)
        {
            if ( $id === false ) {
                $q = $this->db->get('notes')->result();
            }
            else{
                $q = $this->db->where('id', $id)->get('notes')->row();
            }
            return $q;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on the side of the query, because the model in which I move refers to the notes table.

Now I have to somehow pull out the data from domains and compare domains.id with notes.id_domain_rel

At the moment when I put such a code

```
    public function get( $id = false)
    {

        if ( $id == false ) {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('notes');
            $this->db->join('domains', 'notes.id_domain_rel = domains.id');
            $this->db->where('notes.id_domain_rel', 3);

            $q = $this->db->get();
            $q = $q->result();

        }
        else{
             $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $q = $this->db->get('notes');
            $q = $q->row();

        }
        return $q;
    }
```

He receives such data:
[image]

In my opinion, there must be something like this:

```
$this->db->where('notes.id_domain_rel', $domainid);
```

However, I do not know how to extract $domainid.